# CSS3 border-radius parent child question

Tags: css

Let's say I have this css,

```
#wrap {width: 190px; padding: 0 10px; border-radius: 10px; background: #000;}
#wrap a {width: 190px; padding: 10px; display: block;}
#wrap a:hover {background: #fff;}
```

And this html,

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Some Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Some Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Some Link 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Some Link 4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Now the links fit exactly within the #wrap, but the #wrap has a border radius and a black background. Because on hover the links have a white background, the first child element and last child element sit above the border radius corners. But as they sit *on top* the background of the #wrap get hidden hiding the border-radius.

I know I can assign the first and last childs a border radius, but is there an easier way to do this?

There are times when assigning the first and last child a border radius will not work, say if I wanted this on my wrapper div,

```
padding: 5px 10px;
```

Then even if I was to assign a border radius, they will not match making it ugly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` will fix that :)

```
#wrap {
   overflow: hidden;
   ...
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/WF9ty/).

#### Example

[image: Example]

I made the background yellow to see it clearly. As you can see there is some blackness bleeding in on the edge. The example is from Chrome 10 on OS X.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this. I consider myself to have quite a good knowledge of css, obviously not as good as I thought! Don't know how I didn't think of that! Thanks.

Comment: @excanoe You could set a border radius to the child div and make the border radius of the parent div greater than the border radius of the child div by some a few pixels.